# Invalid transfer encoding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, ruby-on-rails-4, post

I'm trying to send XML in a POST.

I'm using this gem: https://github.com/httprb/http.rb

My code:

```
xml_doc  = Nokogiri::XML(@teste,nil,'UTF-8')
resposta =  HTTP.headers(:accept => "Content-Type: application/xml;").post('https://desenvolvedor.moip.com.br/sandbox/ws/alpha/EnviarInstrucao/Unica', :body => xml_doc)
```

I get an error: `Invalid transfer encoding`

In the gem, the origin of this error is in this lines:

```
def add_body_type_headers
    if @body.is_a?(String) && !@headers["Content-Length"]
      @request_header << "Content-Length: #{@body.bytesize}"
    elsif @body.is_a?(Enumerable) && "chunked" != @headers["Transfer-Encoding"]
      fail(RequestError, "invalid transfer encoding")
    end
  end
```

What might be causing this error?

Answer (score 1):

Need write `HTTP.headers("Content-Type" => "application/xml")` instead.

Comment: Just to add onto this, the HTTP gem won't automatically put your content into the correct format to post it in a body. For example, you can't just throw a hash into the body and have it automatically turned into JSON based on the content-type header. You'd need to explicitly call to_json on it. Similarly, I suspect that the Questioner needed to output an actual XML formatted string, and not the Nokogiri parsed doc.